# A collapsible tree in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm currently learning D3.js and playing around with it a bit. Currently I'm working on a tree, which is quite nice and easily done statically.

As I'm trying to avoid just "copy paste" from examples that are already there, and try to read the docs,...well, I face quite a lot of 'problems', and I can't seem to solve this one.

[**Here's a fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnd49ays/1/) of a simple, small collapsible tree. The links do not collapse yet. That would be the next step and not relevant right now.

Collapsing on the root node works as intended. All child nodes vanish. But when clicking on one of the middle nodes that only have one child, it's always the same child that disappears... and I don't see why.

`Click` calls `click` with the clicked node as argument. Within `click`, `toggleChildren` gets called, with the clicked node as argument again. And `toggleChildren` stores the old state and sets the children to `null`...on the clicked node...that's what I thought at least ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined:

```
var node = baseSvg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes);
```

This was missing in your `data`:

```
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
```

And, of course, writting `var i = 0;` before.

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/8ua280wy/

Comment: damn i just found this mistake :P

Comment: Great! That sounds good. What I don't quite understand though,...why do I need to bind an ID to the nodes? I mean,...the data of the tree gets manipulated by 'toggle' in a way that 'children' of the clicked node is null,...so why doesn't that suffice?

Comment: To understand that, please search for "object constancy" (I'm on my mobile now, terrible to share links).

Comment: many thanks, Gerardo! I will have a look at that,...and hope I find what I need :-)